# null pointer doesn't address to 0x0 location in cpp

Tags: c++, pointers, null

I want to evaluate a pointer is null or not by an if condition like below :

```
Model * model; 
if(model == nullptr){
    //do something...
}
```

But this does not work, Strangly the model pointer instead of pointing to `0x0` location it points to 0xcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcd memory location then `model==nullptr` doesn't work for that , i also did `if(model)` , `if(model== NULL)` these are also not working!

any idea about this problem ?

Comment: Please stop spamming irrelevant tags. There is no `nullptr` in **[tag:C]**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An uninitialized pointer need not point to `NULL`. It can point anywhere.

Comment: @M.M That is true, but for that you need to set the pointer to `nullptr` at some point. Until then it is uninitialized, and its contents are determined by the implementation

Answer (score 1):

This code invokes *Undefined Behavior*, since your pointer is **uninitialized**!

You need to initialize your pointer to `nullptr`, and then check for it, otherwise, its value is garbage (it can be anything).

PS: Null pointers must compare equal to the expression `0x0`.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer `Model * model;` will take any random garbage value depending on the memory location at which the pointer gets allocated. C/C++ standards do not mandate that declared but uninitialized pointers be automatically initialized to NULL (or any default value).

Now, I'm not really clear why the pointer is compared to NULL immediately after declaration, but that comparison makes sense after the pointer is assigned a value returned by a function or some expression:

```
Model * model = some_func(/* .. */);  // This would be 
if (model == NULL) {                  // a valid usage
}
```

Answer (score -3):

which IDE you are using if you are using Visual Studio it use NULL like this

but here is the solution

```
Model * model=NULL;
if(model == NULL){
    //do something...
}
```

Comment: Despite being quite slow to support latest C++ standard revisions properly, `nullptr` is supported in MSVC for quite some time. Ever since they started supporting C++11.

Comment: it is not the IDE but the compiler that does support C++11 or not